# Building pry plugin(gem) with bundler

Tags: git, rubygems, bundler, pry

As explained [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Plugins#what-is-a-plugin) pry's plugin require **pry-** prefix. 
I have tried building using bundler:

```
bundle gem pry-name
```

but it messed up directory hierarchies(creating 2 instead of 1 directory):

```
  create  pry-name/pry-name.gemspec
  create  pry-name/lib/pry/name.rb
  create  pry-name/lib/pry/name/version.rb
```

In the gemspec it is using wrong directory structure:

```
  require 'pry/name/version'
```

and in the same file it run this git command:

```
  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
```

which gives, same as above, wrong structure of files

Is there way to *tell* bundler to recognize "-" as valid filename character not as "/"(directory separator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle gem` works according to the Rubygems convention for naming gems, as described at http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/

Note that if you include `gem 'pry-name'` in the `Gemfile` of a project that uses `Bundler.require`, it will use the convention there by default, too, and try to `require 'pry/name'`.

The best workaround is to create a `lib/pry-name.rb` file that just contains `require 'pry/name'`. This keeps your directory structure consistent with the Rubygems & Bundler convention, allowing `require 'pry/name'` to work, while also allowing `require 'pry-name'` to work.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. After I added `pry-name.rb` to git(`git add lib/pry-name.rb`) and builded/installed gem, pry shows this on start: `require 'pry-name' # Failed, saying: Pry is not a module`. My guess is that in my code I'm using `Pry::Commands.create_command` and ruby assume that `Pry` is in `pry-name/lib/pry` directory and it doesn't load `Pry` module from pry gem.

Comment: Here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889569/pry-is-not-a-module Sorry for delay.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to see that you got a solution there. If you think I gave a good answer to your original question about Bundler and the directory structure, it would be nice if you could accept it. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes you were right, but 2 information is missing(one from my 2nd question): running(adding *pry-name.rb* to git) `git add lib/pry-name.rb` and changing every `module Pry` to `class Pry` and I don't know how stackoverflow handle such situation(should I edit your answer or add new answer, or comment(like this one) would be fine?).  Now I accepted your answer, I will add the rest after I check faq(or something), or if you have time, feel free to add it. ps. I should thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks :) I kind of consider the issues of how to add the file to git and the class vs. module thing to be separate questions, but feel free to edit the answer if you like.