# Pry is not a module

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pry

Ok, as @tim-moore asked, I will post it in new question.

Ok, so I wanted to make gem using bundle. Pry extension gem require that gem start with *pry-* as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Plugins#what-is-a-plugin).
I used:

```
bundle gem pry-name
```

but it *messed up* my file structure

```
create  pry-name/pry-name.gemspec
create  pry-name/lib/pry/name.rb
create  pry-name/lib/pry/name/version.rb
```

As you can see it created **lib/pry** directory. I know it's gem's style to created such structure but now I pry cannot load this gem automatically

One solution from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747814/building-pry-plugingem-with-bundler/19782637?noredirect=1#comment29515536_19782637) was:

> create pry-name.rb that contain only `require 'pry/name'`

After I have done this, and build gem, I started pry:
This message appear:

```
require 'pry-name' # Failed, saying: Pry is not a module
```

#### As for my guesses:

I'm creating commands writing something like this:

```
Pry::Commands.create_command "name-of-command" do 
  # my code goes here
end
```

and, as ruby find `Pry::Commands.` it want require it from *lib* directory not from Pry gem.

What does this error mean. Why it doesn't work. How make it work keeping in mind gem and pry requirements(pry gem starts with `pry-` and gem will create another directory(ies) when someone use `-` for example: `gem pry-name` will make `pry/name`)

Comment: Don't expect readers of this question to know your previous questions. Make this question independent. Write everything necessary. Don't expect people to go back to your other question to figure out what you are writing about. And by the way, what is your question? I don't see any.

Comment: @sawa ok, I have edited this quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everywhere in your newly-created gem where it has `module Pry`, change it to: `class Pry`. Since `Pry` is already defined (as a class), you cannot redefine/reopen it as a module.